# Multiply Maps and Images Together OpenCV2

Tags: python, image, opencv, mask

I currently have a salience map for an image using the code below:

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
saliency = cv2.saliency.StaticSaliencyFineGrained_create()
(success, saliencyMap) = saliency.computeSaliency(image)

# cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.imshow("output", saliencyMap)
```

The output is the salience map below. It is normalized (I believe) and the array only contains values between 0 and 1.

[image]

I was wondering if there was a way to put this saliency mask over the image below to get an output image that highlights the salient regions?

[image]

I have tried splitting the image into 3 channels and multiplying each channel by the map and then stacking them back together but this hasn't shown to work. The code I tried was:

```
(B, G, R) = cv2.split(resized)
y = saliencyMap
# cv2.imshow("Blue", B)
# cv2.imshow("Green", G)
# cv2.imshow("Red", R)
# cv2.waitKey(0)

B = B * y.astype(y.dtype)
G = G * y.astype(y.dtype)
R = R * y.astype(y.dtype)


img = cv2.merge((B,G,R))
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

However, the output image I obtained was:

[image]

Which is obviously wrong. Any tips or advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, except that you need to convert your `R,G,B` to `uint8` dtype. As of now they are `float` type (since `saliency` is also float), and float `>1` will be white.

Also, you can use broadcast:

```
output = (img * saliency[...,None]).astype('uint8')
```

And output:

[image]

Comment: So one thing I'm not quite sure about here is that doesn't my code where I put 
 y.astype(y.dtype) already do this for me? What code did you end up writing to get that output image?

Comment: Nvm I realized it's because the array all has values greater than 1. This is definitely what I am looking for! Thank you